# How do I avoid StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when char has no value?

Tags: java, null, char

Sorry if the title made no sense but I did not know how to word it.

The problem:

I'm making a multiple choice quiz game that gets either a, b, c or d from the user. This is no problem if they do as they are told, however if they don't type anything and just hit enter I get a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. I understand why this is happening, but I'm new to Java and can't think of a way to fix it.

What I have so far:

```
    System.out.println("Enter the Answer.");

    response = input.nextLine().charAt(0);

    if(response == 'a')
    {
            System.out.println("Correct");
    }

    else if(response == 'b' || response == 'c' || response == 'd')
    {
        System.out.println("Wrong");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid");
    }
```

Of course the program will never make it past the second line of code if the user types nothing, because you can't take the charAt(0) value of an empty String. What I'm looking for is something that will check if the response is null, and if so ask go back and ask the question to the user again.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: I assume `input` is of type `java.util.Scanner`. If that's the case then it would actually return an _empty string_ rather than `null`.

Comment: Yes, it will be the empty String. That's why `input.nextLine().charAt(0);` will generate a StringIndexOutOBoundsException

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a do-while loop. Just replace

```
response = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

with

```
String line;

do {
  line = input.nextLine();
} while (line.length() < 1);

response = line.charAt(0);
```

This will continue to call `input.nextLine()` as many times as the user enters a blank line, but as soon as they enter a non-blank line it will continue and set `response` equal to the first character of that non-blank line. If you want to re-prompt the user for the answer, then you could add the prompt to the inside of the loop. If you want to check that the user entered a letter a–d you could also add that logic to the loop condition.

Answer (score 3):

Either handle the exception(`StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`) or break this statement

```
    response = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

as

```
    String line = input.nextLine();
    if(line.length()>0){
        response = line.charAt(0);
    }
```

Exception Handling:

```
    try{
        response = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
    }catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException siobe){
        System.out.println("invalid input");
    }
```

Comment: Can `input.nextLine()` ever be `null`?

Comment: @A.R.S.: It has become my habit to put null check before length check. Removed.

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

- Get the input initially as a String, and put it into a temporary String variable.
- Then check the String's length.
- then if > 0 extract the first char and use it.

Answer (score 2):

In addition @HovercraftFullOfEels' (perfectly valid) answer, I'd like to point out that you can "catch" these exceptions. For example:

```
try {
    response = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
} catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    System.out.println("You didn't enter a valid input!");
    // or do anything else to hander invalid input
}
```

i.e. if a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` is encountered when executing the `try`-block, the code in the `catch`-block will be executed. You can read more about catching and handling exceptions [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html).

Answer (score 0):

StringIndexOutofBoundException will occur in the following situation also.

1. Searching a string which is not available
2. Match with the string which is not available

   for ex:

   List ans=new ArrayList();
   temp="and";
   String arr[]={"android","jellybean","kitkat","ax"};
    for(int index=0;index < arr.length;index++ )
    if(temp.length()<=arr[index].length())
     if(temp.equlsIgnoreCase((String)arr[``index].subSequence(0,temp.length())));
      ans.add(arr[index]);

the following code is required to avoid indexoutofboundexception

if(temp.length()<=arr[index].length())

because here we are cheking the length of src string is equal or greater than temp .
if the src string length is less than it will through "arrayindexoutof boundexception"